# How does technique for making a copy of a function works in JavaScript (Storybook example)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, storybook

[Storybook recommends](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/simple-component/) technique for making a copy of a function:

```
const Template = args => <Task {...args} />;
export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

It allows each exported story to set its own properties, but use the same implementation.
I understand result but don't get why it has to bind function to an empty object `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code snippet is using `bind()` on an arrow function:

```js
const Template = args => <Task {...args} />;
export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

Using `bind` on an arrow function does not modify the behavior of the arrow function at all, since the `this` of an arrow function will always be the scope where the arrow function was defined.

MDN recommends not to use `bind` on arrow functions [MDN - Arrow function expressions: call, apply and bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#call_apply_and_bind)

> The call, apply and bind methods are **NOT suitable for Arrow functions** -- as they were designed to allow methods to execute within different scopes -- because Arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within.

```js
const arrowFn = () => {
  console.log('this.foo:', this.foo);
};

window.foo = 'window.foo';
const myObj = {
  foo: 'myObj.foo'
};

const boundFn = arrowFn.bind(myObj);

arrowFn();  // 'window.foo'
boundFn();  // 'window.foo'
```

Since `bind` can't modify an arrow function, the only useful thing `bind` is doing in this example above is creating a new wrapper function that can have its own unique properties.

Therefore, the code from the supplied example:

```js
const Template = (...args) => {};
const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {...};
```

could be replaced with:

```js
const Template = (...args) => {};
Default = function () { Template(...arguments); }
Default.args = {...};
```

This second pattern has the advantage of not using `bind` in a non-standard way.

Comment: This is not true, in any of the affirmations: `bind` does not wrap in a traditional function, the comparison done is not true, the second pattern is not better: is, in fact, another solution (a little bit less optimized) and may not work as expected in all situations.

Comment: @emi - Thanks for the comments. I've edited the answer. Even though the original example "works", I still submit that using `bind` on an arrow function should be avoided (as stated in MDN).

Comment: `I still submit that using bind on an arrow function should be avoided (as stated in MDN)` This is only applicable when the function uses `this`, which is not the case.

Comment: **Note:** The question is specific to [Storybook](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/simple-component/), where `this` is not a part of the specifications and `bind` is used in a well documented way.

Comment: @emi - As a practical matter, documenting a nonstandard pattern is less preferable than using a different pattern in a standard way.

Comment: The thing here is that React Functional Components never use `this`, so the `this` part of `bind` is irrelevant for this specific question: whether the function is arrow or not does not matters and does not responds the question. And this is not a non-standard pattern if you know what you are doing (for example, there is no `prototype` pollution).

Comment: @emi `This is not true, in any of the affirmations: bind does not wrap in a traditional function`.

First line of MDN Description on bind:

`The bind() function creates a new bound function. Calling the bound function generally results in the execution of the function it wraps, which is also called the target function.`

Answer (score 2):

The full relevant code from the link you provided is:

```js
import React from 'react';

import Task from './Task';

export default {
  component: Task,
  title: 'Task',
};

const Template = args => <Task {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  task: {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test Task',
    state: 'TASK_INBOX',
    updatedAt: new Date(2018, 0, 1, 9, 0),
  },
};

export const Pinned = Template.bind({});
Pinned.args = {
  task: {
    ...Default.args.task,
    state: 'TASK_PINNED',
  },
};
```

Using `Template.bind({})` allows for the extra members, such as `Default.args = {...}`, to be defined differently on each copy and from the original (not used here).

#### Edit

As already said in the docs from the link:

> `Template.bind({})` is a [standard JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) technique for making a copy
> of a function. We use this technique to allow each exported story to
> set its own properties, but use the same implementation.

Comment: This: `Template.bind({}) is a standard JavaScript technique for making a copy of a function.` is incorrect. bind does not copy a function. It creates a function that wraps the original function.