# What is the reason for binding arrow function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, storybook

Going through the [storybook documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls)

essentially this part caught my eye:

```js
const Template = (args) => ({
  // Your template goes here
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
```

So I got curious, what is the reason for calling bind on an arrow function? I tried it and the only effect I've seen is that it is hiding the function implementation from `toString`.

```js
Primary.toString()
> 'function () { [native code]  }'
```

Comment: Dupe of [How does technique for making a copy of a function works in JavaScript (Storybook example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054041/how-does-technique-for-making-a-copy-of-a-function-works-in-javascript-storyboo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems completely pointless at first, but it's a way to create a new function that does the same as the original one. In [another example](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#filtering-controls) further down on that page, you can see

> ```
> const Template = (args) => ({
>   // Your template goes here
> });
>
>
> ArrayInclude = Template.bind({})
> ArrayInclude.parameters = { controls: { include: ['foo', 'bar'] } };
>
> RegexInclude = Template.bind({})
> RegexInclude.parameters = { controls: { include: /^hello*/ } };
>
> ArrayExclude = Template.bind({})
> ArrayExclude.parameters = { controls: { exclude: ['foo', 'bar'] } };
>
> RegexExclude = Template.bind({})
> RegexExclude.parameters = { controls: { exclude: /^hello*/ } };
> ```

which creates multiple bound function objects from the same `Template` and assigns different `.parameters` to them.

The same could be achieved with

```
const Primary = Template.bind();
const Primary = Template.bind(null);
const Primary = (args) => Template(args);
// etc
```